# Get FileStream from MVC controller to Client

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I use the code below to put a filestream into a response message, returned by an MVC controller. But how do I get the stream on the client side? Any any comment highly appreciated!
Thanks!

Server:

```
string filename = @"c:\test.zip";

FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open);

HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();

response.Content = new StreamContent(fs);
response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");

return response;
```

Comment: You should probably reword your question to something like, 'How to download file from server using .NET'. Perhaps this can help? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez801hhe(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 8):

If you're simply trying to download the binary data, you should be using the [`FileContentResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.filecontentresult.aspx) type or the [`FileStreamResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.filestreamresult.aspx) type, accessible as the [`File`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.file.aspx) method on the `Controller` class.

Here's a simple example:

```
string filename = @"c:\test.zip";

var bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filename);

return File(bytes, "application/octet-stream", "whatevernameyouneed.zip");
```

You'd probably want to add code to make sure the file exists,etc. If you're curious, you can read about the [ReadAllBytes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes.aspx) method on MSDN as well.

In your WebForms project, you can read the response from this controller rather easily:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var response = await client.GetAsync("protocol://uri-for-your-MVC-project");

if(response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    // Do *one* of the following:

    string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    // do something with the string

    // ... or ...

    var bytes = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
    // do something with byte array

    // ... or ...

    var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
    // do something with the stream

}
```

The manner in which you read the response if up to you; as you haven't really described what the client site is supposed to do with the file you're reading, it's hard to be more specific.

Comment: Beat me to it :)
Here's the MSDN documentation for FileContentResult:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.filecontentresult(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: OK, but what do I do on the client? There I only have a httpresponsemessage. At least, that is what I normally do and i wrap the returned stuff into the response message. Is that not the way to go?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "client"? The controller action will return an octet stream, which normally results in a download prompt in the user's browser.

Comment: on the client use, I use in default.aspx.cs httpclient to get the results from MVC controller.

Comment: basically two different C# projects, one for front end (client) and one for back end (MVC)

Comment: So your client is another ASP.NET application? That's kind of an important bit to leave out of the question.

Comment: oops, sorry. Well, should be independant, coz I guess the front end guys at my job don't like asp.net for front ends, but I just need to make a simple working front end. So ended up with asp.net

Comment: The end result is a binary stream of data, so it shouldn't really matter. If I'm understanding you correctly, you aren't sure how to make the request to the controller and read it's response, from the (I'm assuming) WebForms project?

Comment: Yep, I know how to access the controller (uri), I do get a response on the webforms client project, but I got no idea how to get the data out. So that can be a stream, a filecontent, a filecontentresult .. I am puzzled. Kinda new in this area.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82877/discussion-between-tieson-t-and-ronald).

Comment: Well, need to get some sleep, i can post the webforms client code tomorrow. Thanks anyway for your responses.

Answer (score 3):

If you wanted a little more beefier solution and more control over your file retrieval, feel free to use the following:

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns a file in bytes
/// </summary>
public static class FileHelper
{
    //Limited to 2^32 byte files (4.2 GB)
    public static byte[] GetBytesFromFile(string fullFilePath)
    {

        FileStream fs = null;

        try
        {
            fs = File.OpenRead(fullFilePath);
            var bytes = new byte[fs.Length];
            fs.Read(bytes, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
            return bytes;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (fs != null)
            {
                fs.Close();
                fs.Dispose();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Controller:

```
    public FileResult DownloadPdf()
    {
        var filePath = Server.MapPath("~/Content/resume/BrentonBates_WebDev_Resume.pdf");
        var pdfFileBytes = FileHelper.GetBytesFromFile(filePath);
        return File(pdfFileBytes, "application/pdf", "Brenton Bates Business Application Developer.pdf");
    }
```

Could also review the following: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/125/asp-net-mvc-uploading-and-downloading-files

Hope it helps...

Maybe you were wanting an implementation similar to the following:

```
string fileName = "test.zip";
string path = "c:\\temp\\";
string fullPath = path + fileName;
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(fullPath);

Response.Clear();
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
Response.ContentType = "application/x-zip-compressed";
Response.WriteFile(fullPath);
Response.End();
```

Comment: Thanks, but then again, what to do on my front end asp page. I am using httpclient there (at least, that was my best guess), but how do I get the bytes or filecontent or stream there? I figured a stream was the best solution, since that would have the least impact on memory, right?